2d top down car steering mechanism in godot fails to rotate the car and infinitly spins it instead
I'm trying to code a 2d top down car controls for my godot project.
This is the car controls algorithm and it takes a vector parameter beign the joystick vector so the player's input.
GDScript
extends CharacterBody2D

class_name Car

@export_group("Forces")
@export_range(150, 200) var enginePower := 150
@export_range(500, 1000) var brakePower := 500

@export_group("Limitations")
@export_range(500, 1000) var maxVelocity := 500
@export_range(250, 500) var maxVelocityRev := 250

@export_group("Steering")
@export_range(15, 25) var steeringAngle := deg_to_rad(20)

@export_group("Wheels")
@export_range(20, 100) var wheelDistance := 50

@export_range(20, 50) var traction := 30

var friction = 150

const MINSPEED = 20

func drive(delta: float, vector: Vector2, isBraking: bool) -> void:
    # Transform
    var direction = {
        "forward": -transform.y,
        "right": transform.x,
        "backward": transform.y,
        "left": -transform.x,
        "motion": velocity.normalized()
    }
    
    # Properties
    var acceleration = Vector2.ZERO
    
    # Current direction
    var dot = direction.forward.dot(vector)
    
    # Acceleration
    if (dot > 0):
        acceleration = direction.forward * enginePower * vector.length()
    if (dot < 0):
        acceleration = direction.backward * enginePower * vector.length()
    
    # Braking
    if (isBraking):
        acceleration = -direction.motion * brakePower
    
    # No inputs
    if (vector == Vector2.ZERO):
        acceleration += -direction.motion * friction
        
        # Stop the car if the velocity is very low
        if (velocity.length() < MINSPEED):
            velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    
    # Apply acceleration
    velocity += acceleration * delta
    
    # Limit max velocity
    if (dot > 0):
        velocity = velocity.limit_length(maxVelocity)
    if (dot < 0):
        velocity = velocity.limit_length(maxVelocityRev)
    
    # Rotation
    var front = position + direction.forward * wheelDistance / 2
    var rear = position + direction.backward * wheelDistance / 2
    
    var angle = clamp(vector.angle(), -deg_to_rad(steeringAngle), deg_to_rad(steeringAngle))
    
    front = velocity.rotated(angle)
    rear = velocity 
    
    var heading = rear.direction_to(front)
    
    var d = heading.dot(direction.motion)
    
    if d > 0:
        velocity = lerp(velocity, heading * velocity.length(), traction * delta)
    if d < 0:
        velocity = -heading * min(velocity.length(), maxVelocityRev)
    
    rotation = heading.angle()
    
    move_and_slide()

The car goes forward and backwards but it's not turning.
I asked ChatGPT, watched videos but nothing works.
And I don't know why that happens.
